# Elastic search jar downloading a different version

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I have configured below in build.gradle

```
 compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '6.3.2'
 compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.3.2'
 compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'elasticsearch-rest-client', version: '6.3.2'
```

but it internally downloads 6.8.5 version also. I am not intended for this version(6.8.5). Can someone please help.

Comment: no, it won't can you share your entire Gradle file, some other dependency might be downloading it

Comment: +--- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.3.2 -> 6.8.5
|    |    +--- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:6.8.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:6.8.5

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja pls see above dependency chart-[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.3.2 -> 6.8.5]

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: so you resolved your issue?

Comment: yes i did it was being download by another dependency

Comment: great let me write the answer, it would be useful for the community.

Comment: in a dependent jar 6.3.2 was mention but in main application 6.8.5 was mention thats why both were gets downloaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212239/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-begin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By excluding the problematic(not intended) dependency you can solve the issue.**
**Summary:**
in a dependent jar elastic version 6.3.2 was mention but in main application 6.8.5 was mention that's why both were gets downloaded. OP updated 6.3.2 in the main application also since 6.8.5 not really required for our application.

Elasticsearch specific version never downloads its another version as a dependency and matter of the fact is that in the latest version Elasticsearch server version doesn't match with even minor version of the client, ie Elasticsearch 7.6 server will not work with elasticsearch 7.3 client.